# Can I debug into the source code of stdio within Eclipse CPP?

Tags: c, eclipse

I'm new to Eclipse CPP helios. Does it include the source code of C library like stdio? I want to know how the various functions in stdio are implemented. How can I do it? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The source (or lack thereof) of stdio from libc is a matter for the compiler / Operating System, not Eclipse. You don't mention which platform (Linux, OS X, Windows) you're running, however in general the full source to libc is not installed by default.

The header files, however will be and do have the implementation of some (inline) methods in them. Exact instructions for obtaining source will vary based on your OS, but for example here are some links to [GNU libc](http://www.gnu.org/s/libc/) (Linux), and [Apple's libc](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/Libc/Libc-594.9.5/) (based on BSD).

Comment: Thanks very much. I'm running Windows. I have installed cygwin so I can compile and run the example "Hello World" program in Eclipse. But I cannot trace into puts() function.

Comment: @unix56: Well on Linux you would typically install the *debug* package corresponding to the C library (libc / glibc). I'm not familiar with cwygin's packaging but you could look for a similary-named package there.